# Как пройтись по всем дочерним элементам

Tags: javascript, html

Как можно пройтись по всем дочерним и дочерним дочерних элементов body и удалить определённый класс, если он есть?

Comment: Может быть в вашей ситуации лучше будет сразу найти все элементы с определенным классом и удалить этот класс у таких элементов?

Comment: @smellyshovel, у всех элементов разные классы, а добавлять специально один как идентифицирующий - не благоразумно

Comment: Я не о том. Если вы знаете, какой именно класс вам нужно удалить, то вы можете произвести выборку элементов по этому классу: `document.querySelectorAll(".my-class")`. Или я неправильно понял вашу задачу?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').find('Класс который нужно удалить').removeClass('Класс который нужно удалить');
```

Если нужно удалить вообще все классы

```
$('body').find('*').removeClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var item of document.querySelectorAll('СЕЛЕКТОР_ЭЛЕМЕНТОВ_С_КЛАССОМ')) {
    item.classList.remove('КЛАСС_КОТОРЫЙ_НУЖНО_УДАЛИТЬ');
}
```

Если класс совпадает, то:

```js
document.querySelector('#launch').onclick = function() {
    let classToRemove = 'test';
    for (var item of document.querySelectorAll('.' + classToRemove)) {
        item.classList.remove(classToRemove);
    }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 5px;  
}

.test {
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hello {  
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="/tt/tt" class="test">test a</a>
<div class="test">test div</div>
<div class="hello">hello div</div>

<br><br>
<button id="launch">Удалить класс test из элементов</button>
```